# CounterDown in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a counterdown which will show how much time left for session expire. If user performe some like CRUD operation then counterdown will be reset. If user is not performing any action then counter will stop at 0 second. I am not doing logout or session expire. I want to show counterdown only. Thanks.

I tried below code but it is hardcode 30 minutes. I dont want to hardcode.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };

    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () 
    {var thirtyMinutes = 60 * 30,display = document.querySelector('#time');startTimer(thirtyMinutes, display);};
```

Comment: You can implement `HTTP Interceptors` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests

Comment: So, that on ajax request you can reset the timer

Comment: I guess the issue you're referring to is related to the counter being reset back to initial value when time reaches 00:00. And if my guess is right, you'd need to use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to stop your timer function. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/nain_1304/o06kv3x7/19/